# phalconphp hasMany() and belongsTo() not joining

Tags: php, phalcon

I've been trying to retrieve my data by doing a findFirst() call, but it doesn't work. I've been trying so much and seeking everywhere, but didn't find solution.

I have these tables:

```
- fruit
    fruit_id
    fruit_name
- fruit_color
    fruit_id
    fruit_color_name
```

In my fruit model @Initialize(), I declare:

```
$this->hasOne('fruit_id', 'fruitColor', 'fruit_id');
```

In my fruit_color model, @initalize(), I have:

```
$this->belongsTo('fruit_id', 'fruit', 'fruit_id');
```

When I call find() or findFirst() methods, I can't retrieve anything. when I print out and the debug, I see that no join has been called and I only get a simple SELECT (*).

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not understand the idea of model relations. I will try to explain with examples.

Model relations do not make Joins at all. They will make additional query when you request the related model.

**Model Relations**

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany('id', 'Models\ServicesVideos', 'service_id', [
        'alias' => 'videos',
        'params' => [
            'order' => 'position ASC',
            'conditions' => 'type = :type:',
            'bind' => [
                'type' => get_class($this)
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

With the relation defined above you can use it like so:

```
$user = Users::findFirst(12);
$user->videos; // This will return all videos for this user
```

More info about Model Relations: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models-relationships

---

However if you need to join two or more tables you want to use the **Query Builder**.

```
$lang = $this->getDI()->getSession()->language;
$cacheFile = 'news-'. $lang;
$items = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->columns([
        'main.id',
        'main.title',
        'main.slug',
        'main.summary',

        'upload.id AS imageId',
        'upload.filename AS imageFilename',
        'upload.ver AS uploadVersion',
    ])
    ->from(['main' => 'Models\News'])
    ->leftJoin('Models\Uploads', 'upload.foreign_key = main.id AND upload.section = "newsImage" AND upload.is_active = "1" AND upload.is_default = "1"', 'upload')
    ->where('main.is_active = 1')
    ->andWhere('main.lang = :lang:', ['lang' => $lang])
    ->orderBy('main.ord ASC')
    ->getQuery()->cache(['key' => $cacheFile])->execute();
```

More info about the Query Builder: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models

Comment: Hey there... I was just missing something, the param array in the hasOne/hasMany function :)

Thank you !